# Stack pointer being initialized to 0x0000 on IAR 8 and STL552 Evaluation board used

Tags: windows-10

I am getting the following execution error if I run the program in IAR 8 afer downloading my image to STL552 Evaluation board:

The stack pointer for stack 'CSTACK' (currently 0x00000000) is outside the stack range (0x200002D8 to 0x200010D8)

Comment: My linker file has the valid stack range.   This error pops up either when I give RUN command or after making at least 1 or 2 step in commands

Answer (score 0):

IAR can generate breakpoints of it's own that may or may not correspond with the Stack Location in your project.

Project -> Options -> General Options -> Library Configuration -> 'Library Low-level interface implementation' 
- The "Semihosted" option can lead to IAR placing a breakpoint.
I've set this to 'None' in my project.

Also,
Project -> Options -> Debugger -> 'Use Flash Loader(s)'
- When checked, this can lead to IAR placing a breakpoint as well.

Unfortunately, not using 'Flash Loader(s)' leads to me having to program the device using the ST-LINK Utility.
Afterward, I enter debug mode in IAR using the 'Debug without Downloading' option.

After setting these two options as described, I've stopped seeing this error in my project.